# What is the meaning of underscore before a method name in Java?

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions

I have come across methods like

```
if (_log.isInfoEnabled())
    _log.info("Kicking the Supplier Info at " + importFrom + " with JobID " + jobId);
```

where _ is present before a method name. What does that mean?

Comment: No, `_log` is a *variable* name, not a *method* name. The method names are `isInfoEnabled` and `info` in your example.

Comment: It does not look like _log is a method to me, (or if it is, your not calling it), but an object

Comment: There is no convention that encourages class names starting with underscores.  It's not my favorite; I wouldn't encourage it, either.

Comment: Method names should not have underscores it's a wrong convention.See link here: [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367]

Comment: Ok. Its clear now. Thanks!

Comment: It was (still is ?) a convention used in C++ to denote private members.

Answer (score 2):

An underscore (_) before a variable name or function name doesn't mean anything. It's just the way the programmer has named the function.

You could for example use it to let the other programmers know it is a private function or a global function. It all depends on what you agree with the programmer.